# set SharedPreferences name dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, adapter

I'm using this sequence for designing an app:

(This classes will not change and I'm going to use them for multiple activities)

1. Custom adapter
2. Model Class
3. Shared Preferences

And `Activity` with tab Layouts(with two Fragments) which contains:

I'm going to name this: (Package #1)

- MainActivity
- Fragment One
- Fragment Two

Now I want to duplicate *Package #1* and change some contents then name it as Package #2. But I have a problem here.

I'm using one shared preferences for Package #1, Package #2, Package #3..., right?
please have a look into my shared preferences class:

```
public class SharedPreference_light {

    private SharedPreferences settings;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "Light_Products";
    private static final String FAVORITES = "Favorite_Tones_Light";



    public SharedPreference_light(Context context) {
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();
    }

    private void saveFavorites(List<ProductLocal> favorites) {
        String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);
        editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void addFavorite(ProductLocal product) {
        List <ProductLocal> favorites = getFavorites();
        if (favorites == null)
            favorites = new ArrayList<>();
        favorites.add(product);
        saveFavorites(favorites);
    }

    public void removeFavorite(ProductLocal product) {
        ArrayList <ProductLocal> favorites = getFavorites();
        if (favorites != null) {
            favorites.remove(product);
            saveFavorites(favorites);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList <ProductLocal> getFavorites() {
        List<ProductLocal> favorites;
        if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
            String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
            ProductLocal[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites, ProductLocal[].class);
            favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
            favorites = new ArrayList <> (favorites);
        } else
            return null;

        return (ArrayList <ProductLocal> ) favorites;
    }
}
```

The problem is if I use these two ***variables***:

```
private static final String PREFS_NAME = "Light_Products";
private static final String FAVORITES = "Favorite_Tones_Light";
```

There will be a conflict between those packages. because I'm going to add some list items into shared preferences and use `getSharedPreferences`. then all those items from multiple packages will be added into one shared preferences, and I don't want that.

Now my real question would be:

How can I set shared preferences names(***variables***) dynamically?

**Note:**
I have one usage of shared preferences in custom adapter:

```
private boolean checkFavoriteItem(ProductLocal checkProduct) {
    boolean check = false;
    List<ProductLocal> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites();
    if (favorites != null) {
        for (ProductLocal product : favorites) {
            if (product.equals(checkProduct)) {
                check = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class LocalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LocalAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

private SharedPreference_light sharedPreference;


public LocalAdapter(Activity activity, List<ProductLocal> dataList, RelativeLayout snackLayout) {
    this.snackLayout=snackLayout;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.dataList = dataList ;
    this.dataListFilter = dataList ;
    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference_light(activity);
    methods = new Methods(activity);
}
```

Comment: Just add `Name` to your custom adapter and, later on, route that `Name` below to shared preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you would like to use an interface providing the package name:

```
public interface LightPrefs {

    String getPackageName();
}
```

Secondly, you can reuse your class and make it implementing the previous interface but making it abstract:

```
public abstract class SharedPreference_light implements LightPrefs {

    private SharedPreferences settings;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    protected final String PREFS_NAME = "Light_Products_" + getPackageName();
    protected final String FAVORITES = "Favorite_Tones_Light_" + getPackageName();

    public SharedPreference_light(Context context) {
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();
    }

    private void saveFavorites(List<ProductLocal> favorites) {
        String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);
        editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void addFavorite(ProductLocal product) {
        List <ProductLocal> favorites = getFavorites();
        if (favorites == null)
        favorites = new ArrayList<>();
        favorites.add(product);
        saveFavorites(favorites);
    }

    public void removeFavorite(ProductLocal product) {
        ArrayList <ProductLocal> favorites = getFavorites();
        if (favorites != null) {
            favorites.remove(product);
            saveFavorites(favorites);
        }
    }

}
```

Especially pay attention to some visibility modifiers that have changed.
And finally extend this abstract class in your packages:

```
public class SharedPreference_package1 extends SharedPreference_light {

    private static final String TAG = "SharedPref_package1";

    public SharedPreference_package1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.d(TAG, PREFS_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPackageName() {
        return "package#1";
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class SharedPreference_package2 extends SharedPreference_light {

    private static final String TAG = "SharedPref_package2";

    public SharedPreference_package2(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.d(TAG, PREFS_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPackageName() {
        return "package#2";
    }
}
```

Instantiating both of these classes gives you this log:

```
D/SharedPref_package1: Light_Products_package#1
D/SharedPref_package2: Light_Products_package#2
```

About the adapter, I think you should specify the shared preference object upon construction:

```
public class LocalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LocalAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

private SharedPreference_light sharedPrefs;

public LocalAdapter(Activity activity, List<ProductLocal> dataList, RelativeLayout snackLayout, SharedPreference_light sharedPrefs) {
    this.snackLayout=snackLayout;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.dataList = dataList ;
    this.dataListFilter = dataList ;
    this.sharedPrefs = sharedPrefs;
    methods = new Methods(activity);
}
```

So you can initialise your adapter like this in package #1:

```
SharedPreference_package1 sharedPrefs = new SharedPreference_package1();

LocalAdapter adapter = new LocalAdapter(activity, dataList, snackLayout, sharedPrefs);
```

And you can adapt with SharedPreference_package2 in the second package.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for the reply, In my adapter, there is a usage of shared preferences, wich means based on your answer by initializing `SharedPreference_light` class I have to `@Override` getPackageName there.

Comment: what should be the returning value there... And both Fragments are initializing `SharedPreference_light` too

Comment: Look carefully, in my answer `SharedPreference_light` is an abstract class so it does not need to override `getPackageName()` method.
Also in your fragments, you'll want to use the `SharedPreference*` relevant to the package in which the fragment will be. For instance, a fragment in package#1 should use `SharedPreferencePackage1` which overrides `getPackageName()` returning "package1".

Comment: I'm using abstract `SharedPreference_light` in my adapter as you said, but It needs to `override` getPackageName

Comment: This is the warning `SharedPreference_light' is abstract; cannot be instantiated`

Comment: Can you share you Adapter code, at least how you construct it ?

Comment: Thanks for your generous help

Answer (score 0):

Make your all methods takes shared preferences key as parameter like:

```
public SharedPreference_light(Context context, String name);
private void saveFavorites(List<ProductLocal> favorites, String name);
public void addFavorite(ProductLocal product, String name);
public void removeFavorite(ProductLocal product, String name);
public ArrayList <ProductLocal> getFavorites(String name);
```

Comment: I've thought about this but in my last note, I've mentioned a usage of shared preferences in adapter class. Based on your answer it will change into this :  `List<ProductLocal> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(String name);`

Comment: And I'm using one adapter for all new packages, Still, I'll need to add a dynamic parameter in that method